# Get firebase database of current uid returns undefined

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a page to a  retrieve user's information, but I am getting undefined.

Below is my data structure

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-L4QKxs6d06Vq3amQ7C8" : {
      "content" : "Test",
      "owner" : "D5hkgRIN87OUr3rdSGK1Znws1aB2",
      "title" : "Admin Post"
    },
    "-L4UDg1_glHcqwGjGpTQ" : {
      "content" : "fsdfd",
      "owner" : "D5hkgRIN87OUr3rdSGK1Znws1aB2",
      "title" : "rewsrwr"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "D5hkgRIN87OUr3rdSGK1Znws1aB2" : {
      "posts" : {
        "-L4QKxs6d06Vq3amQ7C8" : {
          "title" : "Admin post"
        },
        "-L4UDg1_glHcqwGjGpTQ" : {
          "title" : "rewsrwr"
        },
        "-L4UDj1vKnTpogjZ26Zg" : {
          "title" : "sdfsdf"
        }
      },
      "role" : "0",
      "username" : "Admin"
    }
  }
}
```

profile.ts

```
export class ProfilePage {
  currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.user = this.db.list(`/users/${this.currentUser.uid}`).snapshotChanges()
    .map(actions => {
      return actions.map(action => {
        return { key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() };
      });
    });
    console.log(this.user.username);
  }

}
```

- "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4",
- "firebase": "4.8.2",

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please don't show images of code.  Copy the code into the question into a code block.

Comment: Same for the JSON. You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson Done.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! took some hints from [angularfire2 issue#396](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/396#issuecomment-236434586)

profile.ts

```
export class ProfilePage {
  currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.db.list(`/users/${this.currentUser.uid}`).snapshotChanges().subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user.payload.val();
  }
    console.log(this.user.username);
  }
```

Comment: any idea why this exact same code would not work on another page.ts?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the

```
.map(actions => {
return actions.map(action => ({
  key: action.key, ...action.payload.val()
}));
```

part to

```
.map(actions => {
return actions.map(action => {
  return { key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() };
});
```

Comment: Still getting undefined when doing this.user.username

Answer (score 1):

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

export class ProfilePage {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth:AngularFireAuth) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      //get current user
        this.afAuth.authState.map((auth) =>  {
        if(auth != null) {
            this.user = this.db.list(`/users/${auth.uid}`).snapshotChanges()
            .map(actions => {
                return actions.map(action => {
                    return { key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() };
                });
            });
            this.user.subscribe(user=>{
                console.log(user.username);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('error getting user...')
        }
        }).subscribe();
  }

}
```

Or you can use it in your template without subscribe

```
<pre>{{(user | async)?.username}}</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am still getting undefined when calling
    `user.username`

Comment: you probably not getting user id `this.currentUser.uid` when the code runs. i updated my answer

Comment: `this.currentUser.uid` is working just fine, I already did a console.log to made sure. Anyways I came up with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648304/get-firebase-database-of-current-uid-returns-undefined/48684031#48684031), and it's surprisingly simple.